# React fetching Data from Node Server using fetch() API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch, components

```
const Table = ({ route, OnAccessBranch, Branche }) => {
    let {Branches, Services, Guichets, items, colNames} = []
    
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/GetTableData)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(Data => {
          Branches = Data[0]
     })

    switch(route){
        case "Branches":
            items = Branches
            colNames = Object.keys(Branches[0])
            return (
                <table className="f6 w-100 ml4 mt2 outline">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {
                                colNames.map((Colonnes, indexMetaData) => {
                                    return(
                                        <th className="fw6 bb b--black-20 pb3 pr3 bg-white tl" key={indexMetaData}> 
                                            { Colonnes.toString().toUpperCase() } 
                                        </th>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody className="lh-copy">
                        {
                            items.map((Ligne, indexRow) => {
                                return(
                                    <tr key={indexRow}>
                                        {
                                            Object.entries(Ligne).map((Cell, indexCell) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <td className="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20" key={indexCell}> { Cell[1] }</td>
                                                )
                                            })
                                        }
                                        <td className="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">
                                            <input type="button" value="Supprimer" name={items[indexRow].REF} className="white b pv2 ph3 bg-red hover-bg-mid-gray bn br2 hover-shadow-inner f3" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td className="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20" id="Guichets">
                                            <input onClick={OnAccessBranch} type="button" value="Guichets" id="Guichets" name={items[indexRow].REF} className="white b pv2 ph3 bg-blue hover-bg-mid-gray bn br2 hover-shadow-inner f3" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td className="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20" id="Services">
                                            <input onClick={OnAccessBranch} type="button" value="Services" id="Services" name={items[indexRow].REF} className="white b pv2 ph3 bg-green hover-bg-mid-gray bn br2 hover-shadow-inner f3" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            )
```

So I have this React functional component that renders any given array of objects.
The problem is in getting the table Data meaning the **Branches** variable must contain an array of objects but the fetch is executing after the switch clause which raises an undefined error since the **Branches** variable is still empty.
Is there a way to load the data into the branches variable before executing the switch clause?
PS: I tried putting the switch clause inside the fetch function **then(Data => { switch.... })** but now the problem became that the component receive a promise object as a **returned value**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use state for this. React will re-render the component (re-run the function) each time a state is updated. So this way the component will render once with `branches` being `undefined` and then once with `branches` having the desired value, meaning you still have to take care of the case when `branches` is `undefined` (e.g. return a loading message).

```js
const [branches, setBranches] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/GetTableData")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(Data => {
       setBranches(Data[0])
     })
}, [])
```

Since the component renders multiple times we need to put it in a `useEffect` to prevent the fetch from being run multiple times.

- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate
- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect